# Experiencing 10s delay in incognito mode

Tags: javascript, wordpress, web, loading

My site is running on generatepress and for some reason I am experiencing delays in content loading.

Website: http://www.finfin.sk

The loading delay happens on category pages in incognito: https://finfin.sk/category/investovanie/

Here is a video showing the load in normal and incognito mode: https://www.loom.com/share/64d00df8cd4d471e8b657390c94ecbaf

I tried to turn off all the plugins and the problem persisted.
Plugins I am using https://prnt.sc/wn6qjf

I have also deleted asynchronous JavaScript plugin and purged cache in `Cloudflare` and turned on developer mode to disable caching. But it did not help.

I am using `Ezoic` and `Cloudflare`. `Ezoic` is integrated through `Cloudflare` so I believe I am using `Ezoic CDN`. I have cleared the cache and the problem was still appearing.

It's weird and I am not sure what could cause this problem.

Any idea how to fix it?

** !!!FIXED!!! **

The problem was in Ezoic. I have integrated Ezoic via Cloudflare. And I saw in the NETWORK under Chrome developer tools *gif files from ezoic, that were taking long to load. This files were preventing content to load only in INCOGNITO Chrome and only in categories. In normal mode everything was loading as it should.

The weirdest thing was that INCOGNITO mode in Chrome and Safari was caching the site. I thought Incognito will never cache the site.

- the developer mode in cloudflare was enabled
- cache was purged in cloudflare and ezoic as well
- I have deleted all the browsing history/cookies/cache from browser
- tested it on 2 different machines
- I have even reinstalled chrome

Anyways thanks for your help.

Comment: So, no code to show?

Comment: Can be related to the cache that is being saved on your computer. On incognito cache isn't being saved (as far as i know). Check the "network" tab under developers tools in order to check which step takes the longest time and which assets delay the loading. Might be the server, the backend, front-end assets, etc. too broad question.